# Office365 Smtp: client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: c#, smtp, office365

You get this crpytic message, which means actually wrong credentionals.

Reset your password, and try again.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question - what is it you're asking for help on?

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 resets it's password without any notification after 2 years. You are able to use outlook.com webmail and exchange, but not smtp anymore. You get this crpytic message, which means actually wrong credentionals.

Reset your password, and try again.